# Spring WebSocket Reactive Client

Tags: websocket, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

I am having quite a hard time conceptually implementing one simple scenario using WebSockets between two backend servers implemented using Spring Boot Webflux and it's WebSocket implementation.

For the sake of simplicity, I will skip the configuration part as I believe it is not relevant in this example.

**Problem:**
I would like to implement a simple scenario where I would have two servers A and B connected with each other through WebSocket. A user sends an HTTP request, server A proxies the request to server B, server B process it and responds back, and the response is returned to the user.

**Implementation:**
Server A (client)

```
private val webSocketClient: WebSocketClient = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()

fun process(request: Request): Response {
    return webSocketClient.execute(URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/websocket")) { session ->
        session
            .send(
                Mono.just(request)
                    .map { objectMapper.writeValueAsString(it) }
                    .map { session.textMessage(it) }
            ).and(
                session
                    .receive()
                    .map { objectMapper.readValue<Response>(it.payloadAsText) }
            )
    }.subscribe()
}
```

Server B:

```
internal class WebSocketHandler(
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
) : WebSocketHandler {
override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {
    val outputMessages = session
        .receive()
        .map { objectMapper.readValue<Request>(it) }
        .map { processMessage(it) }
        .map { objectMapper.writeValueAsString(it) }
        .map { session.textMessage(it) }

    return session.send(outputMessages)
}
```

This approach is not compiling as the subscribe() on the client side return Disposable and I haven't come across a particular example where it would be shown how on the backend I could get the response back to the actual method level where I could return it to the user. Any help or direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: by adding the subscribe in Server A you are basically saying that `Server A` is subscribing to `Server B`. But this is not what you want, you want Client A to subscribe to `Server A` that in turn `Consumes` `Server B`. Which means you should ditch the `Subscribe`. On the otherhand, if you want to establish a Websocket connection between Server A and B and the calling client calls Server A and then places its request/item in the websocket pipeline, you need to use Sinks or create your sequence manually and things get a lot more complex.

Comment: I dont have any magic code laying around, but i can point you in the direction that you should read this chapter https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing and or https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#sinks

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for the suggestions. Mostly my idea, for now, was that server A would be connected to server B via WebSocket and I user would send a request to server A and it would be placed in the WebSocket pipeline as you mentioned. It is a temporary solution but part of the bigger puzzle for later.